# Which is better to use C# and Shader to move textures?

Tags: unity, c#, shaders

We could use C# code `Material.SetTextureOffset` to move a texture, and ShaderGraph can do the same by `Time` and `Tiling and Offset` nodes. So Which way is better for performance purpose?

Comment: Since you already have your options, this type of question (more performant) is generally better answered by yourself in your own specific context... (Also, please keep in mind that "performance" may be about memory, about time, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The primary concern is functionality.

If collisions are needed, the CPU is (mostly) the required method.

I could go into the the specifics of my ancient computer to ask you to identify the hardware first.  That would require to much duplication of code to achieve optimal results.

Select a midrange audience and develop and optimize the code for that group.

For the Intel integrated GPUs, the GPU speed gain is in the low values or negatives.

For today's common computer, the GPU option is only viable for larger games, where a discrete GPU is expected.